# Do kernels provide a basis for a RKHS?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, kernels, fa.functional-analysis

Let $H$ be a Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Space with elements $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, with kernel $K(x, y)$. My question is whether, for some choice of $x_i\in X$, it is the case that $u_i:=K(x_i, \cdot)$ is a basis for $H$. What additional conditions should be imposed on the $x_i$?

Comment: It will depend on what sense of "basis" is meant...orthonormal basis? Riesz basis? something else? (In most reproducing kernel applications, the kernel functions are not orthogonal.)

Comment: In the weakest sense, i.e., not necessarily an orthobasis nor a Riesz sequence. The span of $K(x, \cdot)$ is dense in $H$. I think that if one adds the requirement that $X$ be a separable space, then the result follows.

Comment: In case you are still reading: what precisely do you mean by "weakest sense"? It sounds like you mean something different from "Schauder basis", which is the weakest notion that I've usually seen of "basis"

Comment: @gappy3000 The RKHS is exactly the completion of the span of $\{K(\cdot, x): x \in X\}$.

Answer (score 0):

If {z_n} is not a zero set for the Hilbert space (separable) then K(z_n, .) spans, but is not necessarily a Schauder basis. I believe the sequence needs to be an interpolating sequence for the Kernels to form a Shauder basis.

Comment: Would you mind adding some references?

Comment: @AndrásBátkai Did you ever find a reference/proof to the above claim?