# Orthonormal bases in RKHSs via interpolating sequences

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, hilbert-spaces, kernels, multiplier-algebra

**Definitions and setting**

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a separable, infinite-dimensional, reproducing kernel Hilbert space on a nonempty set $X$.  As usual, denote the reproducing kernel on $\mathcal{H}$ by $K$ and let $K_x:=K(x,\cdot)$.

Let $M(\mathcal{H})$ denote the **multiplier algebra** of $\mathcal{H}$, that is, the functions $f:H\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfying: for all $h\in \mathcal{H}$ one has $x\mapsto f(x)h(x)$ is a function belonging to $H$ (i.e. pointwise multiplication).

A sequence $(k_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}\subseteq X^{\mathbb{N}}$ is said to be an **interpolating sequence** of $M(\mathcal{H})$ if, for any bounded sequence of reals $(r_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}} \in \ell^{\infty}$ one can always find a multiplier $\mu\in M(\mathcal{H})$ satisfying:
$$
\phi(k_i) = w_i \mbox{ for all i in }\mathbb{N}
.
$$
As discussed in the recent article [Tsikalas - Interpolating sequences for pairs of spaces](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jfa.2023.110059), many RKHSs have the property that the set of interpolating sequences can be characterized as the set of sequences $\boldsymbol{k}:=(k_i)\in X^{\mathbb{N}}$ for which $T_{\boldsymbol{k}}(\mathcal{H})=\ell^2$ where
$$
\begin{aligned}
T_{\boldsymbol{k}}:\mathcal{H} & \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}\\
T_{\boldsymbol{k}}(f) & := \big(\frac{f(k_i)}{\|K_{k_i}\|}\big)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}
\end{aligned}
$$
for all $f\in \mathcal{H}$.

---

I recently came across this very old [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/126288/do-kernels-provide-a-basis-for-a-rkhs), claiming that, $(K_{k_i})_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Schauder, or even a Riesz, basis for $\mathcal{H}$ if $(k_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ is an interpolating sequence of $M(\mathcal{H})$.  If this is correct, why is this this the case?

---

**Intuition:**
I expect this somehow follows from the characterization of "good interpolating sequences", by which I mean, those satisfying $T_{\boldsymbol{k}}(\mathcal{H})=\ell^2$; however, I don't really see it….

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that if a sequence $(k_n)$ is interpolating for $M(\mathcal{H})$, then the  *normalized* Kernel vectors $g_n:=K_{k_n}/\Vert K_{k_n} \Vert_\mathcal{H} $ form a Riesz system in $\mathcal{H}$. Of course it does not have to be a complete system, so it is not always a Riesz basis.

To see this, let $g_n$ be the normalized kernel vectors, and for $t\in \mathbb{R}, j\in \mathbb{N}$ define $w_j = e^{2\pi i j t} $. Then by hypothesis, for every $t$ there exists a multiplier $\varphi_t$ such that $\varphi_t(z_j) = w_j,\, j=1,2,\dots$. Furthermore by the open mapping theorem we can choose $\varphi_t$ such that $\Vert \varphi_t \Vert_{M(\mathcal{H})} \leq M < +\infty$. Then consider the adjoint of the multiplication operator by $\varphi_t$, $M_{\varphi_t}^*:\mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$. By the bound on the multiplier norms of $\varphi_t$,
\begin{equation}\label{eq1} \Vert M^*_{\varphi_t} f \Vert_\mathcal{H} ^2 \leq M^2 \Vert f \Vert_\mathcal{H}^2,\,\,\, \forall t\in \mathbb{R}, \,\,\, \forall f \in \mathcal{H}. \end{equation}

Now consider $(a_n)$ a sequence of complex numbers with only finite non zero terms, and $f=\sum_{n}a_n g_n $. Applying the above inequality for this choice of $f$ and using the fact that $M^*_{\varphi_t} g_n = \overline{\varphi_t(k_n)} g_n $ we arrive at the inequality,
$$ \sum_{n,m} a_n \overline{a_m} e^{2\pi i (n-m) t} \langle g_n , g_m \rangle \leq M^2 \Vert \sum_{n} a_n g_n \Vert^2, $$
and integrating with respect to $t$ in $(0,1)$ we find that
$$ \sum_n |a_n|^2 \leq M^2 \Vert \sum_{n} a_n g_n \Vert^2 $$
By replacing $a_n$ by $e^{-2\pi i tn} a_n $ and using the same ineqaulity and integrating with respect to $t$ we find that
$$\Vert \sum_{n} a_n g_n \Vert^2 \leq M^2 \sum_n |a_n|^2. $$
This proves that $g_n$ is a Riesz system.

Comment: Amazing!  Do you know where one could find a reference to this?  It's seems that something which one could find in some book, but I have no idea where to look for sucha a thing.

Comment: Perhaps equally importantly, does a complete intepolating sequence always exist?

Comment: This proof is essentially the one from the book of J. Angler and J. McCarthy "Pick interpolation and Hilbert function spaces". I don't have it now, but I think you can easily track the reference. This one is a bit simplified. Complete interpolating sequences do not always exist. For example in the Hardy space in the unit disc, there exist infinite interpolating sequences but are never complete in the sense that the kernel vectors space the whole space.

Comment: That's very helpful and interesting tbh.  Are there known conditions, perhaps strong conditions, for existence, I googled a while and everything I find is on a case-by-case basis (characterizations in certain classes of spaces) or necessity (as in the above linked paper).

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that, if a kernel has the complete Pick property, then it is complete interpolating if and only if it is interpolating?

Comment: So I think we are confusing two notions here. Complete interpolating I interpret it as a sequence such that $T_k(\mathcal{H} )= \ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ and the corresponding kernel vectors span a dense subspace of $\mathcal{H}$. With this definition being complete interpolating is not equivalent to being interpolating for $M(\mathcal{H})$ even for complete Nevanlinna Pick kernels. While for complete Nevanlinna Pick kernels it is true that a sequence is interpolating for $M(\mathcal{H})$  if and only if $T_k(\mathcal{H}) = \ell^2(\mathbb{N})$.

Comment: Aha, that makes sense; I was also unclear with that. So for sufficient conditions in that case one has these Landau-density type conditions no?

Comment: I mean, could you provide à sufficient condition dor existence?  I'll happily attribué the boundary then :)

Comment: I am not aware of a general sufficient condition which applies to all reproducing kernel Hilbert spaces. I think this question should be posted separately because it is not related to the original one.